# Get Entity Framework returns all navigation objects

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm using the following code to get the objects in EF, the issue is that the returned object has all the navigation objects. For instance an object Customer that has an courseId. When I get that Customer it has the Course object and in the Course his navigation objects and so on. Is this a good approach to for get in a base repository?. Why I'm getting the Customer with all the foreign key Objects instead of just Customer, if I'm not using any Include? I copy the function from the msn page:

[Implementing the Repository and Unit of Work Patterns in an ASP.NET MVC Application (9 of 10)](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

This is the code:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
    Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
    string includeProperties = "")
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

    if (filter != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(filter);
    }

    foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
        (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    {
        query = query.Include(includeProperty);
    }

    if (orderBy != null)
    {
        return orderBy(query).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Question is not clear. What code you call, what results you get, what is the problem?

Comment: It's probably not getting them immediately, but instead it's [`Lazy Loading`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code above If you don't pass `includePropertis` then it doesn't include any proprty and If you pass for example `"Property1,Property2"` it includes Property1, Property2 navigation properties.

If Lazy Loading is enabled (Which is enabled by default) navigation properties are automatically loaded from the database the first time that a property referring to the entity/entities is accessed.

So in this case you can Turn off Lazy Loading this way when you create a context:

```
var db= new YourDbContext();
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

Or this way at YourDbContext class:

```
public class YourDbContext: DbContext 
{ 
    public YourDbContext () 
    { 
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; 
    } 
}
```

For that article a good point to fix it is  constructor of `UnitOfWork` class.

For more information, before continue reading that good article, you can take a look at:

- [Entity Framework Loading Related Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)

Comment: So, I'm getting all the properties because I don't disable lazyLoading?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't get exactly want you need but I'll give you an answer.

For lazy loading works in the entity Costumer, you need this:

```
public virtual Course {get; set;}
public int CourseId {get; set;}
```

That way you get Course get load when you have an object type Costumer,e.g.

```
var course = costumer.Course;
```